# Unable to Pass Exception in Olly Debugger

Tags: ollydbg, seh

I am debugging a program with Olly Debugger. It installs an exception handler while executing as follows:

```
push 004010a9
xor eax, eax
push dword ptr fs:[eax]
mov dword ptr fs:[eax], esp
```

So, the exception handler located at address 004010a9 is installed now.

The next instruction triggers a memory access violation as shown below:

```
add eax, 40
sub dword ptr ds:[00410000], eax
```

Since the code does not have permissions to write to the code section, it triggers a memory access violation and halts.

Now, I have an option to pass the exception to the program by pressing, Shift + F9.

However, when I press, nothing happens and the programs remains at Paused State.

My SEH Chain at this point looks like shown below:

```
004010a9 // exception handler installed above
7c839aa8 // final exception handler
```

My debugging options in Olly Debugger are set as shown below:

Under Exception Tab, I have only the following option checked:

Ignore Memory Access Violations in Kernel32

I am unable to understand why doesn't the program pass exception to the exception handler located at 004010a9 when I press Shift + F9 since it is the current threads exception handler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`check mark ignore the following exceptions` and or range checkbox

`click` the button `add last exception`

`the list box` must be `filled with c0000005 access violation` after you click the button

`press ok` .

`ollydbg is now setup` to allow passing the `said exception` to program

`shift + f9 will only work` now  to pass another exception say divide by zeor this procedure has to be done again

or you can add a complete range like 0 to ffffffff